# Finding the limit of a sequence of functions formally

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let
$$g_n:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$$
$$g_n(x)=\begin{cases}
1 & \mbox{for }x\in[-n, n] \\
x+n+1 & \mbox{for }x\in[-n-1, -n] \\
-x+n+1 & \mbox{for }x\in[n, n+1] \\
0 & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

I want to find the limit of this sequence of functions with the norm 
$$\|f\|_\infty =\sup \{|f(x)|:x\in\mathbb{R}\}.$$
I think that the limit should be $g(x)=1$. However, if we fix $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then
$$\|g_n(x)-g(x)\|_\infty=\sup \{|g_n(x)-g(x)|:x\in\mathbb{R}\}=\sup \{|g_n(x)-1|:x\in(-\infty,-n]\cup[n,\infty)\}=1$$

Where is my mistake? Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: No mistakes in your sup calculations that I can see. :) (Though you shouldn't say that you are fixing $x$, but rather that you are fixing $\color{blue}n$.) It shows that your sequence does *not* converge to the constant function $1$ (in the given metric).

Comment: So what's the limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observation is correct.
You are simply observing that *a function which converges pointwise need not converge uniformly*.

### Pointwise

Fix a specific point $x$. Note that for $n$ large enough, $x$ is
in $[-n,n]$ and hence $g_{n}(x)=1$. It follows that $\lim_{n}g_{n}(x)=1$.
We could summarize this by writing
$$
\lim_{n}\left|g_{n}(x)-1\right|=0\qquad\text{for each point }x.
$$
Less verbosely, we say that "$g_{n}$ converges pointwise to $1$".

### Uniform

As you pointed out, $\left\Vert g_{n}-1\right\Vert _{\infty}=1$.
Therefore,
$$
\lim_n \left\Vert g_n - 1\right\Vert \neq 0.
$$
Less verbosely, we say that "$g_{n}$ does not converge uniformly to $1$".

You should also convince yourself that if a sequence of functions $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$, then it must converge pointwise to $f$.
Using this fact, you can conclude, by the above, that $g_n$ does not converge uniformly (to anything).